# Magento Recurring profile success page

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I'm trying to configure Magento so that if it's a recurring payment through Paypal it goes to a different checkout success page than if it was a normal order, I have found the below in the file /app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php

Could I do a statement to say if recurring payment then redirect to xxxx.html else redirect checkout/onepage/success?

```
 // recurring profiles may be created along with the order or without it
        $profiles = $this->_checkout->getRecurringPaymentProfiles();
        if ($profiles) {
            $ids = array();
            foreach($profiles as $profile) {
                $ids[] = $profile->getId();
            }
            $session->setLastRecurringProfileIds($ids);

        }

        // redirect if PayPal specified some URL (for example, to Giropay bank)
        $url = $this->_checkout->getRedirectUrl();
        if ($url) {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
            return;
        }
        $this->_initToken(false); // no need in token anymore
        $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success/');
        return;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure,

I think you can add an EventObserver on either

```
sales_order_save_before
```

or

```
sales_order_place_before
```

Then do your if-statements and place an redirect there.

You can probably also rewrite the

```
public function saveOrderAction()
```

In

```
Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
```

HTH

Good Luck